# fail to use regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to execute this function:

```
   public function get_referring_domains(){
        $pattern='/<p>Referring<b>Class C subnets<\/b>: <b>(.*?)<\/b> <\/p>/';
        $result=  preg_match_all($pattern, $this->dom, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        return $result;
   }
```

The result that I want to get is a number , as you can see in the pattern that I set, I want to get: ([0-9]+)... But I get 0 every time..why the pattern doesnt match?

This is what I am trying to match:

```
$pattern='/<p>Referring[\s]{1}<b>Class[\s]{1}C\ssubnets</b>:[\s]{1}<b>(.*?)</b>[\s]{1}</p>/i';
```

I get this:

> preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'b'

```
  <p>Referring <b>Class C subnets</b>: <b>4,613</b> </p>
```

It is part of an html page

UPDATE. changed to this:

Comment: What is the input you're feeding to this expression?

Comment: Can you add some clear sample text (not embedded n code) of what you want to be matches?

Comment: An html page ... I want it to search through the page and find the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some whitespace, it should be this:

```
$pattern = '/<p>Referring <b>Class C subnets<\/b>: <b>(.*?)<\/b> <\/p>/';
```

Also, I'd really suggest using DOMDocument instead of regex.

Read this: [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: why to use DomDocument instead of regex?

Comment: Great question! [You can't parse HTML with regex by bobince](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a space after Referring